# how to read and save a server-side pdf with adobe in a client-side web browser? (plugin, applet / java servlet, ...)

Tags: java, pdf, adobe

My need is:

- read a pdf present on a server to display it in a web browser
- save the modifications of the pdf (made by the user) on the server

Currently, I'm using an independent applet that uses a servlet to open a connection between the client and the server. This allows you to read and save the pdf as a byte stream.

I need to do it with Adobe.
Do you know how I can do this? (Plugin, ...)

Thanks

environment: tomcat, java, jsp, internet explorer

Comment: What do you mean by save modifications? Will the users be able to edit the PDF ?

Comment: yes they can add tooltips, change the order of pages, delete pages, ... and changes must be save server side

Comment: So this is currently possible already on client side using your applet right?

Comment: how to link with Adobe Reader on front ?

Comment: Adobe Reader is a Desktop Application, the way I see it is that the user downloads a copy of the PDF and then uploads the changed copy

Comment: To read pdfs, adobe has different ways : plugin, desktop application, other...The goal is to read, edit and save pdfs directly in internet explorer.
Is there an adobe applet or other that would discuss with the server  or can we change the default event of a save button to use the servlet or other to save directly on server-side ?

Comment: I am not sure, but have a look online, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5455334/read-blob-pdf-content-from-database-and-edit-and-output-pdf-edited-file-withou